# NLTK - joining proper nouns after tagging

Tags: python, nltk

I have a sentence which I first tokenize and then tag using nltk:

```
sentence = 'Ronald McDonald exercised at the Central Park on Monday.'

tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
print(tokens)

tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
print(tagged)
```

With the nltk.pos_tag, Ronald, McDonald, Central, Park and Monday become proper nouns (NNP) - which is correct. I now take all the proper nouns of the sentence and write them in another variable as I want to use them later.

```
propernouns = [word for word,pos in tagged if pos == 'NNP']
print(propernouns)
```

Now, in 95% of my cases, any number of proper nouns that follow directly after one another in the text do belong together. "Ronald McDonald" is such a case just like "Central Park" would be.

**Question:** How can I change the code in "propernouns" that it iterates over "tagged", extracts all NPPs and writes them in the variable as it does now - BUT when it finds 2 or more `(<NNP>+)` directly following each other, they are written as a single string separated by a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby` to group consecutive groups of words with the same NNP tag:

```
from itertools import groupby
groups = groupby(tagged, key=lambda x: x[1]) # Group by tags
names = [[w for w,_ in words] for tag,words in groups if tag=="NNP"]
#[['Ronald', 'McDonald'], ['Central', 'Park'], ['Monday']]
names = [" ".join(name) for name in names if len(name)>=2] 
#['Ronald McDonald', 'Central Park']
```